# Linq a list in a Modal and send the value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Well i am trying a new approach and want to do this:

**Model Balance**

```
 public class Balance
{
    public Balance()
    {
        Expenses = new List<Expenses>();
        Earning = new List<Earnings>();
        value = 0;
    }

    public int BalanceId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Earning> Earnings { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    public decimal value { get; set; }
}
```

I have this model, and i wanted to know if it is possible to do a query in Linq to sum all the values from the list of Expenses and earnings and how can i do that,i need this approach cause in my program now, i am doing the loops in the view like this:

**Controller**

```
 public PartialViewResult _ObtemSaldo()
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var balance = db.Balance.Where(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();
        return PartialView(balance);
    }
```

**View**

```
@model MSDiary.Models.Balance



@helper getBalance()
{
decimal balance = 0;
int id = Model.BalanceId;
if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model.Despesas)
    {
        balance-= item.ExpenseValue;
    }
    foreach (var item in Model.Rendimentos)
    {
        balance += item.EarningValue;
    }
    Model.value = balance;
    if(balance < 0)
    {
        ViewBag.color = "red";
                 <p style="color:red">@saldo</p>
            }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.color = "green";
                 <p style="color:green">@saldo</p>
    }
}

}

<h3>Actual balance: <span>@getBalance()</span></h3>
```

I want to know if i am thinking well trying to change the approach, and how can i do the linq query to get what i need

Ps: Sorry for my bad English

Comment: In the controller, `balance .value = balance.Earnings.Sum(x => x.EarningValue) - balance.Expenses.Sum(x => x.ExpenseValue);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your code is ok but i'd move business logic to server side instead. We can create helper (extension) method there. Let's use LINQ (as Stephen Muecke suggested) :

```
public static class BalanceHelper
{
   public static Balance GetBalance(this Balance balance)
   {
      if(balance != null)
      {         
         balance.value = balance.Earnings.Sum(x => x.EarningValue) - 
                           balance.Expenses.Sum(x => x.ExpenseValue);
      }

      return balance; 
   }
}
```

And you can use it in controller after adding namespace that contains it :

```
 using MyProj.Core.MyHelpers;  // namespace with BalanceHelper class

 public PartialViewResult _ObtemSaldo()
 {
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var balance = db.Balance.Where(d => 
             d.ApplicationUserId == userId)
                  .FirstOrDefault()
                  .GetBalance();  // boom

    return PartialView(balance);
 }
```

And in view we can do UI operations :

```
@helper highlightBalance()
{
    if(Model.value < 0)
    {
        ViewBag.color = "red";
                  <p style="color:red">@saldo</p>
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.color = "green";
                 <p style="color:green">@saldo</p>
    }
}

<h3>Actual balance: <span>@highlightBalance()</span></h3>
```

Comment: Your approach is really good, i changed my code and tryed to solve it before coming here in another way, basicly i used the loops i did in the view in the controller and then send the value to the view, saving the value to the database in the controller, what do you think?

Comment: @FilipeCosta Imho it's absolutely normal to use loops instead of LINQ however it's 'dirty practice' to use view to calculate things or execute some business logic on model. Normally this should be done in Core library, in some cases it is done in controller but not in the view.

Comment: That was exactly the reason why i changed my approach, thanks is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

implement `value` as a getter-only property, because code that computes something does not belong in the view:

```
public decimal value => Earnings.Sum(e => e.EarningValue) - Expenses.Sum(e => e.ExpenseValue);
```

If you are not using C# 6, do it this way:

```
public decimal value { get { return Earnings.Sum(e => e.EarningValue) - Expenses.Sum(e => e.ExpenseValue); } }
```